# Erro ao executar código php

Tags: php

O que eu fiz de errado?

```
<?php
$caixa0 = $tempo = echo "HORA: " . date("d/m/y - H:i:s") . "\n";
$caixa01 = $ip = echo "IP: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n";
$caixa1 = echo "NOME: " . $_POST['tNome'] . "\n";
$caixa2 = echo "DATA NASCIMENTO: " . $_POST['outra_data'] . "\n";
$caixa3 = echo "EMAIL: " . $_POST['tEmail'] . "\n";
$caixa4 = echo "PASS: " . $_POST['tPass'] . "\n";
$caixa5 = echo "CPF: " . $_POST['cpf'] . "\n";
$caixa6 = echo "RUA: " . $_POST['tRua'] . "\n";
$caixa7 = echo "COMPLEMENTO: " . $_POST['tCom'] . "\n";
$caixa8 = echo "ESTADO: " . $_POST['tEstado'] . "\n";
$caixa9 = echo "BAIRRO:" . $_POST['tBairro'] . "\n";
$caixa10 = echo "CIDADE: " . $_POST['tCidade'] . "\n";
$caixa11 = echo "CEP: " . $_POST['tCep'] . "\n";
$caixa12 = echo "TELEFONE:" . $_POST['tel'] . "\n";

$file = fopen('logs.txt', 'a');

$escrever0 = fwrite($file, $caixa0);
$escrever01 = fwrite($file, $caixa01);
$escrever1 = fwrite($file, $caixa1);
$escrever2 = fwrite($file, $caixa2);
$escrever3 = fwrite($file, $caixa3);
$escrever4 = fwrite($file, $caixa4);
$escrever5 = fwrite($file, $caixa5);
$escrever6 = fwrite($file, $caixa6);
$escrever7 = fwrite($file, $caixa7);
$escrever8 = fwrite($file, $caixa8);
$escrever9 = fwrite($file, $caixa9);
$escrever10 = fwrite($file, $caixa10);
$escrever11 = fwrite($file, $caixa11);
$escrever12 = fwrite($file, $caixa12);

fclose($file);

header('Location: pagamento.html');
?>
```

O erro que aparece:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /var/www/html/login.php on line 3
```

Comment: Você não precisa de dar um `echo` para passar os valores para a função `fwrite` basta definir as variáveis. Esses echos nas definições das variáveis não são suportados e dão erro  de sintaxe

Answer (score 1):

Tassio, vc esta tentando atribuir a uma variável uma 'echo'. Seria correto atribuir o valor da `String` a variável e depois dar um echo na variável.

Ex:

$tempo = "HORA: " . date("d/m/y - H:i:s") . "\n";
$caixa0 = $tempo;
echo $caixa0;

Comment: Obrigado. Consegui arrumar.